# question application product

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, products

can any one help me in this questions

The perimeter of a square is equal to four times the length of a side of the square. Find the perimeter of a square whose side $s$ measures $2.7$ meters?

thank you

Comment: Well, it says the perimeter is $4$ times the side length, and the side length is given. Do you see how to put these together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

1. Draw a square with length $x$ on each side and find the perimeter of said square.
2. (a)You are to pay $\$299.50$ per month for $36$ months, so how much money have you paid in all? (Further hint: If you have to pay $\$1$ a month for $10$ months, how much money would you have paid.)
   (b) How much have you paid in total? You paid $\$2500$ and all the money from the monthly installments.

Comment: can you please give to me hint of this question

Comment: I have tried to solve please check it is correct or wrong for par (a) $299.50∗36=10782$ part (b) $10782+2500=13282$ thank you

Comment: @leenaadam This is right!